# Height or Width Media Query Not Working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to set up some media queries in my HTML but I'm having a problem.
I would like the query to look at the width and height of the device and use the appropriate stylesheet. It is looking at the height but not the width as far as I can tell. Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 1500px), screen and (min-height: 701px)' href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1499px), screen and (min-height: 501px) and (max-height: 700px)' href="tablet.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 999px), screen and (max-height:500px)' href='mobile.css' type='text/css' />
```

Comment: It might seem a silly question, but what is your goal in loading different CSS based on the height of the window? I would think the width would do everything you need.

Comment: Width seems to be a problem on the Galaxy S4 I'm testing on, it also screws up my layout when the width is max but the height is lower than 700px. For reference here is the page: http://danhufc.com/gaming/

Answer (score 2):

With this code, you can have two stylesheets loaded at the same time. They can interfere with one another, and I guess this is not what you want.

For example width=1200px and height=400px will load tablet.css (because of the width) **and** mobile.css (bacause of the height). I guess this is not what you want. So you have to keep these interactions in mind when you build your CSS rules.

Anyway, most responsive web sites CSS just look at the width to set the appropriate rules.

For example, look how Bootstrap builds its responsive grid system : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Looks like I'm fighting a lost cause with the code I used, think I'll remove it and add some queries into the CSS file instead.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the media queries directly in css. Then you can make the changes according to what elements you want to change styling when in different screen sizes.

You can just do:

```
 @media all and (min-width: 1500px) and (min-height: 701px) {
  // Add the styling for the elements you want to respond to the screen change
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply and this is the route I'm going to take, I liked the idea of separate stylesheets but it was making life far too complicated.